# Any tips for finding other practical uses of tech in your world

Tags: technology, science-fiction

In sci fi, writers tend to make a new technology to solve a problem, for example artificial gravity for spacecraft via gravitons. But seldom do they use the full application of gravity generation (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QUqCJrBqcvQ). Maybe gravity generation isn't the best example, but my point is how do you find other practical applications of technology in your Setting?

In my setting, there are metamaterials which can bend the path of Microwaves, I originally created this to make efficient beamed power for spacecraft, and to act as lensing for microwave telescopes. However I am not sure if there are more applications for this technology. Is there a method or tip to find out other uses of technology?

Comment: Please give us a well defined problem, not a fishing for ideas hint.

Comment: In my setting, there are metamaterials which can bend the path of Microwaves, I originally created this to make efficient beamed power for spacecraft, and to act as lensing for microwave telescopes. However I am not sure if there are more applications for this technology. Is there a method or tip to find out other uses of technology.

Comment: @spaceamoeba1010 I guess you should focus on this metamaterial problem then. It's too hard to find a general tip, since I doubt there's any besides "well, use the concept to the full-extent!". Something which is... Welly belly and honestly, a not very helpful tautology. As you focus on your issue, you should also decide on a domain you want to expand the uses : (Weapons, transport, healthcare...?), along with giving as many details about your technology as you can. This way people'll be more able to help you out.

Comment: as a rule of thumb: any technology that is able to concentrate and direct energy can - and will - be used as weapon. and as for "Is there a method or tip to find out other uses of technology?" - yes. it's "thinking about it". toying with ideas. experimenting.

Comment: «efficient beamed power for spacecraft». Question: how much power could you efficiently beam on an unwilling spacecraft, its evasion manoeuvers notwithstanding? (Asking for an enemy).

Comment: ??? You have a material which can refract microwaves. In the real world, we have a material which can refract light, namely glass. With glass we make lenses, used in telescopes, microscopes, magnifying glasses, headlights, lighthouses and so on. With your material you can make the same kind of appliances, using microwaves instead of visible light. Look around you and identify all objects containing a lens.

Comment: @AlexP Drinking glasses too.

Comment: What is a metamaterial?

Comment: @Daron: A [metamaterial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamaterial) is a material with some sort of small-scale structure which provides interesting properties with respect to some sort of waves. (Small scale with respect to the wavelength of the waves of interest.) There are metamaterials which interact with electromagnetic waves, and metamaterials which interact with mechanical (= acoustic) waves.

Comment: If you've ever played the *Mass Effect* series of games, you'll know that almost all of their fancy sci-fi tech turns out to be some form of gravity manipulation.  (It's kind of in the name after all.)  But that's one example of a fictional world doing many non-obvious things with artificial gravity.

Comment: FYI, such a metamaterial could also be used to make something effectively invisible by curving light around itself (this doesn't address black-body and other self-radiation though).

Answer (score 8):

## Analyse the technology according to common applications and the six types of technology.

According [to this article](https://www.indeed.com/career-advice/finding-a-job/types-of-technology) there are six common types of technology. One way to find out what a power can do is to use that framework.

1. Communication. Microwave bending could allow stealthy communication which evaded detection. It could boost the signal and power of wifi.
2. Computers. Mostly relating to the above, massively boosted signalling could allow much more powerful networks of computers, beaming precise microwave signals to each other. The most powerful AIs could rely on microwave bending to coordinate themselves. Microwave cameras could provide people with a decisive advantage in combat, seeing through walls so they could target enemies or cloaking themselves in a stealth field that avoided microwave detection.
3. Energy storage. You already noted beaming power. I googled microwave batteries, and [apparently microwaves can be used to make cheap, sustainable batteries.](https://www.chemistryworld.com/news/cooking-up-sustainable-battery-materials-in-the-microwave/4014798.article) so you can have microwave batteries which serve as cheap and efficient energy storage. They're heavier, but microwave batteries could be the key to making unreliable renewable power cheap and reliable.
4. Manufacturing. [Microwaves can be used to manufacture precisely shaped metal parts.](https://www.nature.com/articles/news990617-2) so any large scale engineering project may rely on microwaves to manufacture key parts quickly and efficiently.
5. Medical. Microwaves can be used to scan people's bodies for cancer, to burn out bad things like cancer, and could be a key medical technology. Microwave monitoring devices could ensure the health of sick people much more cheaply.
6. Transportation. Cars could easily rely on microwaves to make them much more effective. Powerful microwave networks could coordinate vast numbers of AI cars. Cheap batteries could power them, and swapping them out would be easy and efficient. The ability to bend microwaves could provide much more safe travel by detecting danger and bypassing water and other barriers, and allow moving at much greater speeds.

And all of these can be turned to war, of course. Better communication lets you coordinate wars, computers let you number crunch wars, energy storage and projection lets you shoot at enemies with twisty microwaves, manufacturing and logistics wins wars, medical technology can be used to heal soldiers and enhance them, and transportation lets you move supplies faster.

Comment: Hmm, I think that you could add Demolition/Destruction/Disposal to this list.  It's a lot more important than we generally recognize.

Comment: Another category would be direct military application - maybe OPs microwave bending would make masers a viable weapon?

Comment: I added a note about military applications. That tends to be an indirect use of technology. Masers and exploding things is an application of energy storage, for example. You just direct the stored energy to explode your enemy.

Answer (score 2):

**Refraction of Microwaves**

"bend the path of Microwaves" is called REFRACTION. Already there are materials which refract microwaves e.g. plasma, wax etc. Experiment on refraction of microwaves using semi-cylinder of wax is mentioned [here](https://www.yorku.ca/marko/PHYS2212/Lab6). Refraction of microwaves using paraffin prism is mentioned [here](https://www.studocu.com/row/document/national-university-of-technology/physics-ii-lab/experiment-reflection-transmission-and-refraction-of-microwaves/15116216). Refraction of microwaves using Ethafoam Prism is mentioned [here](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/%7Ephys128/experiments/microwave/microwave.pdf).

**Negative refraction of microwaves**

A metamaterial made of a multilayer planar arrangement of flat unit cells was used to fabricate a prism that was used to demonstrate [negative refraction](https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/figure/10.1119/1.3537122) at the prism-air interface.

**Applications of this phenomenon:**

As studied [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/350193030_AN_APPLICATION_OF_MICROWAVES_REFRACTION_FOR_INHOMOGENEOUS_PLASMA_DIAGNOSTIC)

> **An Application Of Microwaves Refraction For
> Inhomogeneous Plasma Diagnostic**
>
> A brief review of the main microwave diagnostics methods of
> inhomogeneous plasma based on the refraction of  microwaves is  given.
> These methods make it possible to determine the plasma density
> distribution, the  magnetic  field  distribution,  the  electron
> collision  frequency,  and  the  electron  temperature  profile. In
> addition,  the  determination of the average density of the peripheral
> plasma layers and the local inhomogeneities of the rotating  plasma
> are also possible. The effect of refraction on the accuracy of
> determining the plasma parameters by using  microwave methods for
> plasma diagnostics is considered.

As studied [here](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-021-01644-1)

> **Colossal magnetic fields in high refractive index materials at microwave frequencies**
>
> It is shown that GHz radiation illuminating a high refractive index
> ceramic sphere creates instant magnetic near-fields comparable to
> those in neutron stars, opening up a new paradigm for creation of
> giant magnetic fields on the millimeter's scale.

Comment: Although the information you presenting is interesting. I was asking if there was a method to find alternative uses for any technology in you make up in a setting.

Comment: We invent a technology for a particular purpose in mind and then we think of other applications depending on its properties as told by @Daron. We need to know the PROPERTIES to **find out other uses of technology**.

Answer (score 2):

**Find out How stuff works**

> Is there a method or tip to find out other uses of technology?

The method is to study real technological thingies. How does a telephone/computer/telescope/rocket/space station/encryption network/nuclear power plant/MRI scanner work?

Once you know how the various parts of the thingy fit together, you might notice it simplifies or works better if THAT part was a microwave-refracting metamaterial.

You might also find a machine that refracts SOMETHING and wonder can that SOMETHING be replaced with microwaves using your new material. Congratulations, you have invented the microwave-equivalent of what you started with.

Whether it does or not not will of course depend on the proposed properties of your material.

For example is the new material harder, lighter, or more temperature resistant than the other refracting medium already mentioned, namely glass?

**Note:** AlexP says glass does not work to refract microwaves and I believe him.

Comment: Glass does not work for microwaves. That's the entire point of research into metamaterials which can be used to make microwave lenses in the same way that we make glass lenses for visible light.